# JAX-RS jersey ExceptionMapper: How to know the method who threw the exception

Tags: java, rest, jersey, jax-rs

Im using JAX-RS jersey ExceptionMapper, and I'm wondering if there is a way to know inside the method toResponse(), which method (from the API) threw the exception.

Example (dummy code)

```
@javax.ws.rs.Path(“/bookstore/books/{bookID}”)
public class Book {
    @javax.ws.rs.GET
    public String informationMethod(String user) {
        ...
            throw new Exception("Error");
        ....    
    }    
}



@Provider
public class SomeMapper implements ExceptionMapper<Exception> {
    @Override
    public Response toResponse(Exception ex) {

        //a way to get the method name that threw the exception. 
        //In the above example is: informationMethod.
        String methodName = //informationMethod

        return Response.status(500).entity(ex.getMessage()).type("text/plain")
                .build();
    }
}
```

Comment: Why do you want to do that? Typically, you'd use different exception types to generate different responses via different exception mappers. Is that not a good solution for you?

Comment: You should never expose your backend component in your response (for example java packages or class or methods or line of codes), instead use http status code or customize the response body with appropriate message.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, it is a good solution, but what I really want to know is which method threw the exception. I need it for example: to log the method name.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, I dont want to expose my backend component in my response. What I really want to know is which method threw the exception.

Comment: One way to find this using client.Even i faced the same problem with my project. So to trace the out the error you can use the client code for your local testing.

Answer (score 9):

You can provide some information from context to your `ExceptionMapper`.

```
package your.rest.pckg;

import java.lang.reflect.Method;
import java.net.URI;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.container.ResourceInfo;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Context;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MultivaluedMap;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Response;
import javax.ws.rs.core.UriBuilder;
import javax.ws.rs.core.UriInfo;
import javax.ws.rs.ext.ExceptionMapper;
import javax.ws.rs.ext.Provider;

@Provider
public class SomeMapper
                implements ExceptionMapper<Exception>
{

    @Context private HttpServletRequest request;

    @Context private HttpServletResponse response;

    @Context private ResourceInfo resourceInfo;

    @Context private UriInfo uriInfo;

    @Override
    public Response toResponse( Exception ex )
    {
        String method = request.getMethod();
        String pathInfo = request.getPathInfo();

        Class<?> resourceClass = resourceInfo.getResourceClass();
        Method resourceMethod = resourceInfo.getResourceMethod();
        URI resourcePath = getResourcePath( resourceClass, resourceMethod );

        URI requestUri = uriInfo.getRequestUri();
        MultivaluedMap<String, String> pathParams = uriInfo.getPathParameters();
        MultivaluedMap<String, String> queryParams = uriInfo.getQueryParameters();

        // define your object to provide data through response
        Object responseEntity = ex.getMessage(); 

        // do your stuff

        return Response.status( Response.Status.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR )
                       .entity( responseEntity )
                       .type( MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON )
                       .build();
    }

    private static URI getResourcePath( Class<?> clazz, Method method )
    {
        if ( clazz == null || !clazz.isAnnotationPresent( Path.class ) )
        {
            return null;
        }

        UriBuilder builder = UriBuilder.fromResource( clazz );
        if ( method != null && method.isAnnotationPresent( Path.class ) )
        {
            builder.path( method );
        }

        return builder.build();
    }
}
```

See

- [HttpServletRequest.java](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest.html)
- [HttpServletResponse.java](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletResponse.html)
- [ResourceInfo.java](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/container/ResourceInfo.html)
- [UriInfo.java](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/core/UriInfo.html)

Instead of `Excpetion` you can also map `Throwable`.

To pass through `WebApplicationExcpetion`s just add following if clause at the beginnig of `toResponse()` body:

```
if (ex instanceof WebApplicationException)
{
    return (( (WebApplicationException) ex ).getResponse());
}
```

---

You can also use all of the `@Context` fields in your resource class `Book`.

Comment: Does this example work with instance variable? It works only with class variable uriInfo. Please help

Comment: A link to @Ashwini (resolved) question: https://stackoverflow.com/q/49670142/586790

Comment: I tried to add @Context private ResourceInfo resourceInfo; in my ExceptionMapper class but when I call resourceInfo.getResourceMethod() or resourceInfo.getResourceClass() I'm getting null values. Any advice?

Answer (score 1):

Inject in to your ExceptionMapper mapper:

```
@Context private ResourceInfo resourceInfo;
```

as it was suggested and do the following to get a method name:

```
resourceInfo.getResourceMethod()
```