# Why instance variable inside Custom Exception Mapper has to be static?

Tags: java, spring-boot, exception, jersey, jax-rs

I have implemented a custom exception mapper in order to throw the bad request in my application. Here's the code:

CustomFilterBadRequest:

```
package com.test.exceptions;

import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Response;
import javax.ws.rs.ext.ExceptionMapper;
import java.util.Date;

public class CustomFilterBadRequest extends Exception implements
        ExceptionMapper<CustomFilterBadRequest> {

    private String uriInfo;


    public CustomFilterBadRequest() {
        super("Invalid Request. Please try again with the valid request");
    }

    public CustomFilterBadRequest(String uriInfo, String message) {
        super(message);
        this.uriInfo = uriInfo;
    }

    @Override
    public Response toResponse(CustomFilterBadRequest exception) {
        return Response.status(400).entity(new ErrorDetails(new Date(),
                400, "bad request", exception.getMessage(),this.uriInfo)).type(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON).build();
    }
}
```

**Issue:**

**Note:**
In this example, I have an instance variable called uriInfo. 
From another service, I do :

```
throw new CustomFilterBadRequest("uri","message")
```

Immediately, the constructor gets called and my uriInfo is set to the value "uri". After this, toResponse method gets called.My uriInfo instance variable is reset. why? Whereas, when I made the instance variable to be static, the value is retained.

I am unable to get any documentation on this. Please help.

*****UPDATE*****

When the REST End point related to this exception is invoked, the default constructor of CustomFilterBadRequest is invoked creating an object with state uriInfo initialized to null. Let's call this object as object1.

when we do throw new CustomFilterBadRequest("uri","msg"), an object is created with state uriInfo initialized to the value uri. Let's call this object as object2.

JAX-RS Runtime maps the CustomFilterBadRequest exception to the exception mapper which is also CustomFilterBadRequest here. Hence toResponse method gets called. It gets uriInfo from object1. (which is obviously null here)

And there's no necessity that we should use only class variables inside Custom exception mappers.

This kind of implementation is quite confusing. I have updated with the straightforward implementation in the answer below.

Comment: "why instance variable has to be static" ... do you understand what static means? either it's an instance variable, or it is static, you can't have it both ways. Can you provide an example an a bit better explanation of what is happening?

Comment: My guess: you are not passing the correct instance of the exception to your toResponse. I don't even get why you should pass an instance

Comment: It's not the same instance, I can't see other option. As a fix I could suggest to change a bit the implementation - add your own exception handler, catch specific exceptions with if/switch and construct the response there.

Comment: Note that in `toResponse` you get message from the passed `exception` but `uriInfo` from `this`.

Comment: You'll need to post the code which uses `CustomFilterBadRequest`, calls `toResponse` etc. Basically, a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that the `toResponse(...)` method is called on the instance of `CustomFilterBadRequest` that is registered with the JAX-RS runtime. If the no-arg constructor is used in registration that is why uriInfo always has it's default value of null.

I would recommend that you have your exception defined in one class, and you Exception handler defined in another.

Exception:

```
public class CustomBadRequest extends Exception {

  private String uriInfo;

  public CustomBadRequest() {
    super("Invalid Request. Please try again with the valid request");
  }

  public CustomBadRequest(String uriInfo, String message) {
    super(message);
    this.uriInfo = uriInfo;
  }

  public String getUriInfo() {
    return uriInfo;
  }
}
```

ExceptionMapper:

```
@Provider
public class CustomFilterBadRequest implements ExceptionMapper<CustomBadRequest> {

  @Override
  public Response toResponse(CustomBadRequest exception) {
    return Response.status(400).entity(new ErrorDetails(new Date(),
      400, "bad request", exception.getMessage(),exception.getUriInfo())).type(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON).build();
  }
}
```

Comment: I hope you realize that this statement: "The problem is that the toResponse(...) method is called on another instance of CustomFilterBadRequest. That is why uriInfo always has it's default value of null." is nonsense?

Comment: I don't think it's nonsense. My understanding is that the `ExceptionMapper`is registered with JAX-RS runtime and called when a handler method throws this type of exception. Hence the registered mapper should be another instance than the later created and thrown exception.

Comment: stating that it will be always null, is nonsense. that would only be the case if the instance of which the variable would be used, didn't set the value, which, according to the constructors, is highly unlikely.

Comment: the no-arg constructor would not set this value. And if you would set the value with the other constructor it would defeat it's purpose, e.g. you would always get the same `uriInfo`

Comment: i updated my answer to clarify what I think is the problem

Comment: if they had used the default constructor, they could have gotten that from the (different) error message. Since they state they only get a different uri, this is not the case.
The problem they have, as was already stated in the comments, is that they get  the message from one instance of the exception, while they get the uriInfo from another instance

Comment: Yes, you are saying the same thing that I'm implying. And I have provided an example that I think will fix the issue. That is getting the correct uriInfo in the mapped exception.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer @ Par Nilsson

Answer (score 0):

I understood the reason behind the issue.

Whenever we hit the end point, default constructors of exception mappers registered with the jersey is called and objects of each type are created with state initialized to default values of its type.

When the custom exception is thrown, the custom exception object is created and JAX-RS runtime searches for the exception mapper to map the exception. If none is found, it just maps to the default exception mapper. If the custom exception mapper is found, toResponse method is called. In this case, we should get the states of customexception from its object itself inside the toResponse method.

I needed this to obtain uriInfo inside exceptionmapper.

Here's the working code:

CustomFilterBadRequest.java

```
public class CustomFilterBadRequest extends Exception {

public CustomFilterBadRequest(String message) {
    super(message);
}
```

}

CustomFilterBadRequestExceptionMapper.java

```
public class CustomFilterBadRequestExceptionMapper implements ExceptionMapper<CustomFilterBadRequest> {

private UriInfo uriInfo;

public CustomFilterBadRequestExceptionMapper(@Context UriInfo uriInfo) {
    this.uriInfo = uriInfo;
}

@Override
public Response toResponse(CustomFilterBadRequest exception) {
    return Response.status(400).entity(new ErrorDetails(Instant.now(),
            400, "bad request", exception.getMessage(),this.uriInfo.getPath())).type(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON).build();
}
```

}

Thanks a lot everyone for the response.

Answer (score 0):

Im pretty sure this is all you have to do:

CustomFilterBadRequest:

```
package com.test.exceptions;

import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Response;
import javax.ws.rs.ext.ExceptionMapper;
import java.util.Date;

public class CustomFilterBadRequest extends Exception implements
        ExceptionMapper<CustomFilterBadRequest> {

    private String uriInfo;


    public CustomFilterBadRequest() {
        super("Invalid Request. Please try again with the valid request");
    }

    public CustomFilterBadRequest(String uriInfo, String message) {
        super(message);
        this.uriInfo = uriInfo;
    }

    @Override
    public Response toResponse(CustomFilterBadRequest exception) {
        return Response.status(400).entity(new ErrorDetails(new Date(),
                400, "bad request", exception.getMessage(),exception.uriInfo)).type(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON).build();
    }
}
```

I just changed `this.uriInfo` to `exception.uriInfo`

Basically, when you throw a CustomFilterBadRequestException, JAX-RS creates a new instance to map the exception you threw. This new instance has a default value of uriInfo. So thus it is not saved.

Whatever you do, don’t make `uriInfo` static. That would cause huge concurrency issues.